# Creating a survey with a question being lookup column with filtering

Tags: lookup-column, filter, survey

So I need to create a survey on a monthly basis with just one question.

Possible answers should be the values from a lookup column, but limited only to those from the previous (calendar) month.

Is it possible to create such survey using some OOTB solution, or maybe creating some Custom Web Part using SPD?
Or it requires coding the whole thing with VS?